# How to search for only jpg files in a directory using c#

Tags: c#, directory

I want to search a directory and get the list of all jpg files. The code that I have is as follow:

```
string[] fileList = Directory.Exists(this._imageDirectory)
                                            ? Directory.GetFiles(this._imageDirectory, "*.jpg")
                                            : null;
```

This is working well if I have files such as below:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.txt
```

in the above case it finds only two files. But if I have the following files:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg_tmp
```

it finds 3 files. It finds 3.jpg_tmp which it should not find it.

How can I fix it without looking into all fileList and finding the ones that are not correct?

Answer (score 2):

look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) extract from MSDN

When the extension is exactly three characters,GetFiles would return all the extensions that match and that **starts with** that 3 letter extension.

So, `*.jpg` would match hello.jpg,hello.jpger,hello.jpgworld

Insted use `hello?.jpg` which would match hello.jpg exactly.

---

To solve your problem you can use String's `EndsWith` method as done [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21905551/598420)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list with LINQ:

```
var pictures = fileList != null ? 
        fileList.Where(name => name.EndsWith(".jpg")).ToArray() : 
        Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

?.jpg will only return files with a single character before the ".". Need to do as user2720372 suggests and filter the list.